# any solution like T4MVC for external JS files?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc, client-side-scripting, magic-string

I m using T4MVC in MVC project. My question is is there such a solution for external JS files ? Many times there need to use URLs or strings (to compare) in external JS files. A change in sting break application. Or please advice T4MVC can be used for same.

Highly appreciate your time, help and sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Try [T4MVCJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4MVCJS/)

We got it to work on a proof of concept project, However we managed to delete that project and cannot get it to work with any of our existing projects. Maybe you'll have more luck than us.